# Webpack resolve images in certain directory

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, bundling-and-minification

I have my images in `/assets/images`, and my code in `/src`.

To reference the images from `/src`, I have to currently do this:

`require("../assets/images/some-image.png");`

Is there a way that I can simplify this so that I don't need to specify the image path? Potentially just requiring `image!some-image.png`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by using `resolve.alias`:

```
resolve: {
    alias:{
        "~images": path.resolve("./assets/images")
    },
    extensions: [ '', '.js', '.jpg' ]
}
```

I can then use `require("~images/test.jpg");` to get me `./assets/images/test.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable with the path and reference that.

```
var imagePath = '../assets/images/';
require(imagePath + 'some-image.png');
```

or with ES6 template strings

```
const imagePath = '../assets/images/';
require(`#{imagePath}some-image.png`);
```

Comment: Both of those still require me to put the image path into the require statement in some form. I would like to just require it in a similar way to saying "I want an image called this"